# How can I pass a specific variable from a file to another variable with user input

Tags: python

I have a function that configuring the network interface.
it ask the user for new IP address/netmask/gateway/ and DNS and write the new values to the /etc/network/interfaces file:
before it written to the file I have another function named: "vaildIP" that check if the user input for IP address is correct and then pass the new values to the interfaces file.

```
address = vaildIP ('Address[current value is <no-value>:')
netmask = vaildIP('Netmask[current value is < no - value >]:')
gateway = vaildIP('Gateway[current value is < no - value >]:')
dns = raw_input('DNS servers [current value is <no-value>]:') or "8.8.8.8"
```

so my question is how can i read the /etc/network/interfaces file and add the current value to the other variable where its no-value

for example, it should be:

now its: no-value

```
address = vaildIP ('Address[current value is <no-value>:')
```

i would like it be:

```
address = vaildIP ('Address[current value is 192.168.1.34:') * or any other ip
```

so far i manage to open the file and print the values but i cant pass the values to the place where its `no-value`:

```
with open("/etc/network/interfaces", "r+") as file:
     file_content = file.readlines()
     for line in file_content:
        if line.startswith("address") or line.startswith("netmask") or line.startswith("gateway") or line.startswith("dns-nameservers"):
            print 'current values are -- {lineip}'.format(lineip = line)
```

can someone help me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#variables to store info available in /etc/network/interfaces file
    address_value = '<no-value>'
    netmask_value = '<no-value>'
    gateway_value = '<no-value>'
    dns_value = '<no-value>'

    with open("/Users/yossi.s/Desktop/interfaces.txt", "r+") as file:
     file_content = file.readlines()

     #read data from /etc/network/interfaces and store in variables
     for line in file_content:
        if line.startswith("address"):
            address_value = line.strip()
        elif line.startswith("netmask"):
            netmask_value = line.strip()
        elif line.startswith("gateway"):
            gateway_value = line.strip()
        elif line.startswith("dns-nameservers"):
            dns_value = line.strip()

    address = vaildIP ('Address[current value is {val}]:'.format(val=address_value))
    netmask = vaildIP('Netmask[current value is {val}]:'.format(val=netmask_value))
    gateway = vaildIP('Gateway[current value is {val}]:'.format(val=gateway_value))
    print "[Network Interface] Please provide the DNS servers to use (one or more, separated with spaces), \n  or press Enter `enter code here`to use the existing value."
    dns = raw_input('DNS servers [current value is {val}]:'.format(val=dns_value)) or "8.8.8.8"
```